# Independent sampling with at least two elements, without re-sampling

Tags: sampling

Suppose we have a sequence of numbers (WLOG, [n]) and we want to sample elements from it into a set $S$, where each element is sampled independently at random with
`$p_i := Pr[i \in S] \in (0, 1), for each i \in [n]$`.

We do this multiple times, and each time we need to at least sample two nodes.
Otherwise, we discard this sampling and re-sample.
A naive way to implement this is to sample as usual sequentially, and re-sample from scratch if we end up with less than two elements.
Are there better one-shot ways to do so without re-sampling?

In our case, the sequence becomes smaller and smaller along the process.
I have tried the naive way, but it can take long time in a later stage, when the sequence becomes too small.

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
vector<int> sampled_nodes;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (dis(gen) < alpha) {
        sampled_nodes.push_back(i);
    }
}
auto num_sampled_nodes = sampled_nodes.size();
// if the number of sampled nodes is less than 2, then we can skip this round
if (num_sampled_nodes < 2) {
    continue;
}
```